# Shared pre-subscribed RxJS observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an observable and I need it to act like a promise, i.e. the chain should be executed *once* on creation and result in hot observable.

Here's an example:

```
console.log('0 ms');

var foo$ = new Observable(obs => obs.next(1))
.map(v => {
  console.log('map, ' + v);
  return v + 1;
})
.share();

foo$.subscribe(); // would like to skip this

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('100 ms');
  foo$.subscribe(v => { console.log('subscribe, ' + v); });
});
```

It results in desirable output:

> 0 ms
>
> map 1
>
> 100 ms
>
> subscribe 2

The observable needs to be subscribed with extra `subscribe()`, and I would like to avoid that.

But this won't work with completed observables:

```
console.log('0 ms');

var bar$ = new Observable(1, 2)
.map(v => {
  console.log('map, ' + v);
  return v + 1;
})
.share();

bar$.subscribe(); // would like to skip this

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('100 ms');
  bar$.subscribe(v => { console.log('subscribe, ' + v); });
});
```

Desired output:

> 0 ms
>
> map 1
>
> map 2
>
> 100 ms
>
> subscribe 2
>
> subscribe 3

Real output:

> 0 ms
>
> map, 1
>
> map, 2
>
> 100 ms
>
> map, 1
>
> subscribe 2
>
> map, 2
>
> subscribe 3

Observable chain is re-executed on every subscription.

`Observable.of` and increment map are used as an example. Both observable and its chain can be costly, so the chain should be executed only once, similarly to a promise. But I can't just switch to promises because there can be more than one value in completed observable.

Another concern is that promises are susceptible to GC and won't result in memory leaks. I'm not sure if observable subscriptions can guarantee that.

How can an observable be pre-subscribed with operator to avoid dummy `subscribe()`?

How can can completed observable with multiple values be pre-subscribed and avoid multiple chain execution?

Can such observables be garbage collected, similarly to promises?

*There are similar answered questions but I believe they don't address all the concerns*.

Answer (score 0):

> The observable needs to be subscribed with extra subscribe(), and I would like to avoid that.

You can't. Subscribing is what executes an observable, period. It's like saying you want to call a function `myFunc` without having to write the parentheses `myFunc()`.

There are way to »hide« doing this, but they significantly change what is happening. And the subscription still happens, it's just hidden in the operator (which you still have to call). For example, you might have to `connect` instead.

> How can an observable be pre-subscribed with operator to avoid dummy subscribe()?

Generally speaking, you want to *multicast* your observable. There are quite a few operators to achieve this, from the raw `multicast` to `publish`, `share` and various `publish*` and `share*` variations. They all do slightly different things, so which one to use depends on what you want to do.

> Can such observables be garbage collected, similarly to promises?

If you manage your subscriptions properly, GC will be no problem. But you do need to make sure that all subscriptions end when they are no longer needed.

---

I find myself unable to give a specific answer to achieve the output you posted as desired because it doesn't make sense to me. Since you map the emitted values (1, 2) to their successor, the resulting observable emits 2 and 3. I don't understand why subscribing should emit only 2, but not 3.

Comment: *It's like saying you want to call a function myFunc without having to write the parentheses myFunc()* - this works for promises. *so which one to use depends on what you want to do* - it's very specific behaviour that is described in the question. My primary concern is completed observable. *only 2, but not 3* - sorry for that, it's a typo. Of course, `subscribe 3` will be there, too.

Comment: There's no operator which just connects a multicast observable »right away«, so you'll need to call `connect` yourself. If you are OK with executing the observable on first subscription, you can add `refCount` (e.g., publishReplay + refCount). I don't quite understand the aversion to calling `subscribe`, to be honest.

Comment: That said, you can write a function which takes an observable, subscribes to it with a ReplaySubject and returns that subject. That way you get an »immediate« subscription.

Comment: subscribe is not a big problem, it just looks like a hack and I wondered if there's a better solution (e.g. I can't have `foo$ = ...` as single line in class field because there's no room for `subscribe()` statement). Thanks, I'll investigate my options further with ReplaySubject.

Comment: The common usecase is executing the observable on the first subscription, hence the refCount. You can always do that subscription in the constructor as the "loading" process so the first real subscriber doesn't have to wait. But I'd advise to look at specific examples to discuss the best strategy.